# method not available: solc (solidity compiler) not found

Tags: solidity, json-rpc, solc, ruby

I am using ethereum-ruby to deploy smart contracts. I am using JSON RPC calls to my geth and its working pretty well. But when i use `compile_solidity` I get:

```
"error"=>{"code"=>-32603, "message"=>"eth_compileSolidity method not available: solc (solidity compiler) not found"}}
```

and if I do `get_compilers` it returns `""`.

I installed solc it with npm. What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved this by installing solc with `apt-get` like

```
sudo apt-get install solc
```

Then I typed `which solc` and it told me it was installed at `/usr/bin/solc`.  So I fired up `geth console` and used the command

```
admin.setSolc('/usr/bin/solc')
```

to point to the path. Then it worked.